# Can a wizard learn spells from other wizards that were not in the same group?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, tomb-of-annihilation

In Adventurers League can a wizard learn spells from other wizards that were not in the same group? What if they have already met in the past adventures?

We know that is possible trade magical objects between characters that are not in the same table spending 15 extra downtime days, in order to let them meet each other and make a deal. Can the same rule be applied to let 2 wizards meet outside the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

The rules for the copying spells downtime only permits players that are playing the same adventure together.

> **Two or more characters playing the same adventure together** using this downtime activity can allow one another access to their spellbook; effectively “trading” spells between everyone involved to copy as normal.

The rules only explicitly allow copying spells from players at your table. If there was a process for trading spells between players who are not at the same table, it would specify it or there would have been no reason to specify that the rule as stated was between two players in the same adventure to being with.

Compare this to the rule on trading magic items which says:

> [C]haracters can trade permanent magic items received in play with one another on a one-for-one basis.[...]**If you’re trading with another character playing in the same adventure as you**, the downtime cost is waived. Consumable magic items (scrolls, potions, and magical ammunition) can’t be traded.

Comment: Where is there a chance of failure when copying spells?  I don't see anything that mentions that in the PHB.

Comment: @PhilBoncer Found it: [How do you calculate the chance of failure when copying spells in Adventurers League?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105675)

Comment: Ah, so no chance of failure with sharing spellbooks, just in copying from scrolls.  OK.  Just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed something.